# Timezones in Rails 5 when using beginnig_of_month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

My Rails 5 app is set to BRT (Brazilian timezone) and my Postgres database to UTC. I never had to worry about that because Rails always calculated the correct time when reading from or writing to the database. So for example when I had an input field with `time = 15:00` it would write `18:00` to the database and when reading from the database it would return `15:00` again. Perfect!

But now I want to write the beginning of the month to the database:

`Time.now.beginning_of_month` which is `2017-04-01 00:00:00`

```
Payment.create(
  :time => Time.now.beginning_of_month
)
```

Now it writes exactly this (in BRT) to the database without converting to UTC. When I read this from the database later it converts it to BRT `2017-03-31 21:00:00` which is wrong.

Of course I could convert the time to UTC before saving it to the database. But I find it strange that Rails always took care of converting and in this case it does not.

I hope the problem became clear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good article about this subject:

https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/

Basically what I had to to is change `Time.now` to `Time.current` as Time.now ignores the timezone settings.